# Howto re-install my HP laptop with preinstalled Windows Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista

When I boot my HP laptop, it shows "missing operating system" and it restart, this repeat over and over.

Pressing F11 for the Recovery Program don't works as it also show the same error - "missing operating system"

I boot up the laptop with my Win7PE CD, but I can't access my C and D drive through the file explorer and CMD

No CD/DVD was supplied for the laptop when I bought it.

My laptop is pre-installed with Windows Vista Home Premium 32 bit. I would like to ask:
Can I format my C and D drive? Will the hidden OEM partition been formatted?
If I can't format my laptop/the formatting action will destroy my OEM partition, what should I do?

Comment: In the BIOS, is the HDD detected?

Comment: @Miles Hayler BIOS can detect my HDD

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot with Windows Vista/7 disk, and repair Windows.

Here is what you can try.

Boot the Windows 7 or Vista DVD, choose `Repair`

In the System Recovery Options dialog box, choose the drive of your Windows installation and click **Next**.

In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click **Startup** Repair.

Open a Command Prompt.

Enter the following commands:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr

bootrec.exe /fixboot

bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

Press Enter.

Also see this link [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392)

Comment: It cant detect my drive

Comment: Are you sure is your hard drive healthy? Can you check it in Bios? Whether your system can detect your H.D.D?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and from what I see searching the web, you are likely missing the intel drivers or other drivers for your disk controller for the c drive.  In my case it looks like it is related to having a hybrid drive.